# display hyperlink in Output ipywidget with link

Tags: python, output, jupyter, display, ipywidgets

I want to add to an output ipywidget several links

So far I do:

```
with wd_LINKS_output:
    display('mylinks: ')
    now= datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    display(now)
    display('https://www.google.com/')
```

I get:

[image]

I would like:
a) get rid of the ''
b) Get a clikable link

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get rid of the `'` marks unless you create a Text Widget for each line. That is just the way Python and IPython displays strings.

For a cleaner display of your text and links, use the HTML Widget in ipywidgets:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

text = widgets.HTML('Hyperlink below:')
link = widgets.HTML(
    value="<a href=http://www.google.com target='_blank'>Go to Google</a>",
)

display(text)
display(link)
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how I can set the font-size of the hyperlink? The usual layout way doesn't appear to work out.

Comment: You can use normal html formatting tags https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp